# sql get list from table1 and join it with another table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following two tables:

**Table1**

```
id  name
---------
A3  B2
A3  B400
A5  B100
A7  B200
A8  B6
A8  B2
A8  B3
```

and **Table2**

```
id  name    company
-------------------
A1          company1
A2          company2
A3  B1      company3
A4          company4
A5  B2      company5
A6          company6
A7  B3      company7
A8  B4      company8
A9          company9
A10 B6      company10
```

and the result is like:

```
mysource    target Freq
-------------------
A3          A5      1
A3          B400    1
A5          B100    1
A7          B200    1
A8          A10     1
A8          A5      1
A8          A7      1
```

**here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41ea0/5/0)**, but it is not returning the results i am looking for.

some explanations:
get the list of all ids from table1, (include the repeated ones as well) as MYSOURCE in the new table, and for the TARGET column, get the value from name column of table1 as the value for column TARGET, but first check if that exists in the name column of table2, if exists, then take the corresponding id from table2, if it doesn't exist, then put that name value from table1 in the target column.
here is my attempt:

```
select t1.id as mysource,
        CASE              
             WHEN t1.name = t2.name THEN t2.id
             ELSE t1.name
          END AS target, 
        '1' as size
      from Table1 t1
      join Table2 t2
      on t1.id = t2.id      
      group by mysource
```

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh Mysql is not that strict about GROUP BY and the columns in select. But it is not clear for the ungrouped columns, what you get in there. Could be from a different row than the grouped column.

Comment: @Seb, depends on which MySQL version. Newer versions are strict (unless in compatibility mode.) IMHO it's a bad idea to depend on an unpredictable, deprecated "feature".

Comment: @jarlh With this I totally aggree.

Comment: @seb so what should i do in this query then?

Comment: @jarlh: According to the SQL standard, a column must be in GROUP BY or aggregated or functionally dependent on the group. Many DBMS fail here, because it is hard to determine functional dependency. So the general rule you are stating is the rule of those non-compliant DBMS. marcel's query would be fine and standard-compliant, in case t1.id were unique for t1 and t2.id unique for t2...

Comment: ... MySQL was not compliant in the regard that it didn't even bother to check functional dependency and let thus pass faulty queries. With ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY set, MySQL tries to detect functional dependency. In case of doubt it declares the query as faulty. So marcel's query may or may not pass in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode. That depends on whether functional dependence is given and if so on whether MySQL is able to detect it. @Seb

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I know my "general rule" perhaps seems to be a bit unfair considering functional dependency. However, if you follow it you'll always be safe, no matter which dbms you're using. (Also, we don't know the table definitions here.)

Comment: In any case, there is no group by needed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to join based on the name, why do you put the id in the on-clause of the join? You need a left join or all rows from table 1 with no corresponding name in table2 will be removed.

```
select t1.id as mysource,
    IFNULL(t2.id, t1.name) AS target, 
    '1' as size
  from Table1 t1
  left join Table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
```